# APIPlatform : AccessDeniedException from UserCheck seems not catch exception while exception_to_status parameter is activate

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I use APIPlatform v2.4.
I implemented a JWT auth and everything works fine. 
But I want to add a check to login : If a user is inactive, I want to block access, so I use UserCheck according to the synfony cookbook :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html

So I created a AccessDeniedException and It works fine.

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }

        if ($user->getIsActive() == false) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('Inactive account');
        }
    }
```

But, I want to convert this AccessDeniedException in 404 error like in apiplatform documentation :

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/#errors-handling

So I add this configuration setup in my api_platform.yaml :

```
error_formats:
    jsonproblem: ['application/problem+json']
exception_to_status:
    Symfony\Component\Finder\Exception\AccessDeniedException: 400
```

But nothing to do...when I try to log in my app I have a HTML error :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <title>    Inactive account (500 Internal Server Error)
</title>
```

Is there anyone who had a similar problem?

Thank you for readding,

Comment: Just a side note, but you should be using the `AccessDeniedException` from `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception`. This is the right one in this context. Will not solve your problem, though. I wonder why you want to throw an 404 in the first place. 403 would be more appropriate and I think this comes out of the box when using the Exception I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, 403 is more appropriated. But you're right too it, it's not solve my problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Has mentionned @chrisissorry, you should use `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException` instead of `Symfony\Component\Finder\...`.

In my case I have the same problem that you but maybe for a different reason, I've a "global Exection" catcher that return `500` (eg : `Exception: 500`)
I though, the `exception_to_status` from api platform work like the firewall security :
More precise first and global after.
But now I don't think so.

So I've commented my 'global' exception and now my accessDenied works like a charm.

Here is my `exception_to_status` from `config\packages\api_platform.yaml` :

```
# config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    # ...
    exception_to_status:
        # The 4 following handlers are registered by default, keep those lines to prevent unexpected side effects
        Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExceptionInterface: 400 # Use a raw status code (recommended)
        ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: !php/const Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\FilterValidationException: 400
        Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException: 409

        # 40X
        Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException: 400
        Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 404
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException: 403
        Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException: 404
        Doctrine\ORM\NotFoundException: 404
        NotFoundException: 404

        # 50X
        # Exception: 500
```

You can see that I've commented the `500` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think api-platform actually does not catch custom exception codes in exception_to_status config.

I've just found a workaround to deal with it :

- Do not change anything in `config/packages/api_platform.yaml`, you don't have to define custom exception_to_status.
- Default exception_to_status mappings contains `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExceptionInterface: 400`
- So, **implements this interface in your custom exception class**.

And... that's it! You will have a 400 status code WITH (this is what I wanted) your custom exception message ! No more default "Internal Server Error" message in the API hydra:description.

Because now, the `ErrorNormalizerTrait` of api-platform works like expected even if `$debug=false` to keep the custom message.